# JavaScript replace multipile numbers in string

Tags: javascript, replace

I tried to make a JavaScript function that replace a number with a higher number but I cannot get it to work.

I've tried many things with no luck.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function change(text) {
 var array = {"1":"6", "2":"7", "3":"8", "4":"9", "5":"0", "6":"1", "7":"2", "8":"3", "9":"4", "0":"5",}

 for (var val in array)
    text = text.replace(new RegExp(val, "g"), array[val]);

 return text;
}

document.write(change('123456789'));
</script>
```

This returns `123401234` but it should return `6789012345`

I also tried this:

```
function change_new(text) { text = text.replace(/1/g, "6").replace(/2/g, "7").replace(/3/g, "8").replace(/4/g, "9").replace(/5/g, "0").replace(/6/g, "1").replace(/7/g, "2").replace(/8/g, "3").replace(/9/g, "4").replace(/0/g, "5"); return text; }
```

with the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use multiple replace calls or you will replace numbers you've already replaced. Use replace with a function as the replacement instead:

```
var numbers = {"1": "6", "2": "7", ...};
text = text.replace(/\d/g, function(match) {
    return numbers[match[0]]; // [0] is the entire matched text, which is one digit
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Now is it possible to replace all dots (.) with commas (,)? I tried to add it to the variable numbers but the dots/commans remains invisible.

Comment: @Ole: Did you remember to update the regex to match dots as well? Otherwise it won't even call the function for a dot. `/[\d.]/` Remembering to update both is a hassle though so you might want to turn it into a simple loop that constructs a new string instead of using regex, if you change it a lot.